# Connection between class instance and static method in IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a question about calling static methods in IronPython via class instance. Let's say I have next static method:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def SomeMethod(number):
        return number + 10

SomeMethod = staticmethod(SomeMethod)
```

I can call this method via class instance without any problems:

```
instance = SomeClass()
instance.SomeMethod(1)
```

But what about case when I want to return some values from self object via static method. Consider next case: I initialized field of this class object  with some value in constructor and want to return this value from static method. Then I should somehow provide dependency between my object and my static method. My class looks like this:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def SomeMethod(self, number):
        return self._numberValue + number + 10

SomeMethod = staticmethod(SomeMethod)

    def __init__(self):
        self._numberValue = 10
```

I try to call my static method exactly the same way:

```
instance = SomeClass()
instance.SomeMethod(1)
```

But then I got error : 'SomeMethod() takes exactly 2 argumets (1 given)'. Is there possibility to provide connection between class object and static method? Or this just makes no sense?)

Answer (score 1):

A "normal" (non-static) class method receives a reference to the instance (`self`) implicitely as first parameter.

If you define your method as static, you have to pass an instance explicitely:

```
instance = SomeClass()
instance.SomeMethod(instance, 1)
```

Note that `self` is not a magic keyword, it's just a convention. You could use any other name for that variable if that makes it clearer:

```
def SomeMethod(inst, number):
    return inst._numberValue + number + 10
SomeMethod = staticmethod(SomeMethod)
```